# CodeIgniter global settings database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to implement global settings to each controller and views.

Having database table named ***config*** containing

```
config_name | config_value
title        | My Website
email       | my@example.com
```

In my ***model*** I have query:

```
function config()
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->get('config');
    return $query->result();
}
```

In ***controller*** I call model data this way

```
$data['cfg'] = $this->config_model->config();
```

Now I want to display certain bits of config in ***view*** by using

```
<title><?php echo $cfg->title; ?></title>
```

But I get an error **Trying to get property of non-object**

I tried result query options in ***model*** query:

```
result();
result_array();
```

But it won't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what you get if you dump $this->config_model->config(); in controller?

Comment: same error. nothing changed.

Comment: your model inherit from CI_Model? If its not, it may cause $this->db object not found. Try go upper and dump $db in your model

Comment: it is inheriting from CI_Model

Comment: The error what you got is calling method on none object. Try debug config model if is object, then go upper and debug $db in your model if is object, if is null, your connection is fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have simplified things and solved it this way:

Changed database table layout to 1 row

```
title | email | country | city
```

And now it works. Previously i wanted db layout different, but i'll go with this now.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your model:

```
public function config() {
  $q = $this->db->get('config')
return $q->result_array();
```

And this in your controller:

```
$this->load->model("config_model");
    $res = $this->config_model->get();
    if($res){
        $data['result'] = $res;
        $this->load->view('Your view here', $data);
    } else {
        echo "failed";
    }
```

And then you can access like this in your view:

```
$result[0]['title'];
```

Assuming your config table only has one row.

Answer (score -1):

can be used like that

your model:

```
public function get() {        
$query = $this->db->get('config');        
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
    {
        $data[$row->item] = $row->val;

    }                      
    return $data;
} 
return false; 
}
```

use in the controller:

```
$this->load->model("config_model");           
$config = $this->config_model->get(); 

echo $config['title'];
```

use in view:

```
$this->load->view('index',$config);
```

result:

```
<p><?=$title?></p>
```